# Rails : Paperclip MissingRequiredValidatorError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I have a polymorphic resource in my rails app :

```
class Media < ActiveRecord::Base
  # some stuff
  belongs_to :mediable, :polymorphic => true
  # some stuff

  class Media::TeaserCroppedImage < Media
   has_attached_file :attachment,
                :styles                => ...,
                :processors            => ...,
                :path                  => "...",
                :url                   => "...",
                # ...

   validates_attachment :attachment, matches: { file_name: ["image/jpeg", "image/jpg"] }
```

As you can see, I tried to add the paperclip validator. But apparently, it doesn't work, and I still get the error MissingRequiredValidatorError.

Is there a problem with the syntax of the validator ?

Comment: Isn't that should be `validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have to include a content_type validation, something like this:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg"]
```

or you can replace your current validation with this:

```
validates_attachment_file_name :attachment, :matches => [/jpe?g\Z/]
```

Comment: Problem is, when I try this, I have this error : `undefined method 'attachment_content_type' for #<Media::TeaserCroppedImage:0x007fbd02b89428>`. Indeed, my attachment doesn't have a content_type. Only usable thing seems to be the file_name.

Comment: How about this? `validates_attachment_file_name :attachment, :matches => [/jpe?g\Z/]`?

Comment: Had to wait a certain time before accepting an answer ;)

Comment: oh i see, it was too quick ;)